# Is Ubuntu using my discreet GPU?

Tags: ati, graphics

How can I be sure that Ubuntu is using my discreet GPU? Here are my `lshw` results if you want to check out my specs. In short, I have a laptop with an Intel i5 processor, which of course has its own integrated graphics chip. Along with that, I have a 2GB AMD Radeon 7730M discreet GPU. Animations feels slow and sluggish on Ubuntu 13.04 compared to Windows 8 (which I have on another partition). Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

[lshw results](http://www.pasteall.org/44725) (It was a bit too long to post as a code block here. )

Answer (score 0):

Here is a similar question with an accepted answer:   [Switching between graphics cards](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2419/switching-between-graphics-cards)

I can't seem to flag this question as a duplicate. Somebody help?