# disable intel gpu in ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, nvidia

I am wondering if there is anything to disable the intel gpu on ubuntu 12.04. I want to be able to setup dual monitor using nvidia-settings. It seems the intel gpu is used for display as suggested by

```
sudo lshw -c display
```

the output is

```
  *-display               
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: NVIDIA Corporation
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: a1
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=nvidia latency=0
       resources: irq:16 memory:c0000000-c0ffffff memory:90000000-9fffffff memory:a0000000-a1ffffff ioport:4000(size=128) memory:a2000000-a207ffff
  *-display
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Haswell Integrated Graphics Controller
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 06
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
       resources: irq:47 memory:c2000000-c23fffff memory:b0000000-bfffffff ioport:5000(size=64)
```

I have a lenovoY410 with GT750M. It seems there is no way to turn off the intel gpu in bios either. Help please. Thanks.

Comment: look [here](http://xpressrazor.wordpress.com/2013/08/15/install-and-debug-amd-catalyst-graphics-driver-in-elementary-os-ubuntu-12-04/) and [here](http://xpressrazor.wordpress.com/2013/07/22/install-catalyst-driver-in-ubuntu-12-04-2/): at the end there is a part saying "Switching between AMD and Intel graphics cards" -  it may work for nvidia. also, [this question](http://askubuntu.com/q/2419/47206), to which yours might be flagged as duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install a driver from your additional drivers section
like nvidia-340 + install nvidia-prime + enable performance mode
in nvidia-settings